# What is the impact of warnings when compiling in gcc? What can be the consequences?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I've had that doubt for several days. Does anyone have any experience to tell about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: consequences can vary from insignificant to significant.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava For example?

Comment: Check the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example if you have your function named `someFuncWhichReturnsLong` which returns `long` and then somewhere you assign result of it to `int`, you might get a warning that `long` might not fit inside `int` - however, if you know that **in your case** that function `someFuncWhichReturnsLong` never returns value larger than `int`, you can ignore that warning.

On the other hand if you get a warning that you are using an incorrect format specifier say in `printf`, ignoring this will end up in undefined behavior.

In general you should never ignore warnings, and check what it is trying to say.

Comment: Thank you so much, very clear.